# undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id'

Tags: c++, makefile, openssl, linker

I am running into an issue building my program.

I installed openssl from git source using

```
./config
make
sudo make install
```

which created the directory in /usr/local/ssl, I then used in my Makefile:

```
all: amalgam clean

security.o: security.cpp
    g++ $< -I/usr/local/ssl/include -c -o $@ -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto 

amalgam.o: amalgam.cpp
    g++ $< -c -o $@

amalgam: security.o amalgam.o
    g++ $^ -o $@

clean: 
    -rm *.o
```

What is odd is the build for security.o goes fine, but I get an issue when it tries to build the final program (amalgam).

```
g++ security.cpp -I/usr/local/ssl/include -c -o security.o -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto 
g++ amalgam.cpp -c -o amalgam.o
g++ security.o amalgam.o -o amalgam
security.o: In function `amal_sec::genkey()':
security.cpp:(.text+0x2b): undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:11: recipe for target 'amalgam' failed
make: *** [amalgam] Error 1
```

amalgam.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>

#include "security.h"


using namespace std; 
int main (int argc, char ** argv){
    amal_sec new_sec;
    new_sec.genkey();

}
```

security.h

```
 #include <openssl/evp.h>
 #include <openssl/rsa.h>

class amal_sec
{   
    public:
        bool genkey();
};
```

and security.cpp

```
#include "security.h"

bool amal_sec::genkey(){ 
    printf("Generating a Key\n");

    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;

    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, NULL);
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. In the makefile the `-L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto` needs to be added to the linker command line in the `amalgam` rule to specify the additional libraries to be linked in, rather than the compiler command line for the `security.o` rule.

Comment: Perfect. This solved my issue. Thank you!!