# Problems with RSA key generation when using openssl 3.0

Tags: c, openssl

When trying to compile the following code based on the openSSL reference code (https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.0/man3/RSA_generate_key.html)

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
int main(){
    EVP_PKEY*pkey=EVP_RSA_gen(1024);

}
```

It throws the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccLRNWp1.o: in function `main':
rsa2.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_Q_keygen'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm compiling with the next command.

```
gcc  -I/usr/include/openssl/ rsa2.c  -lcrypto -lssl
```

And my openssl version is

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022 (Library: OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022)
```

What I might be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved following [undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60714855/undefined-reference-to-evp-pkey-ctx-new-id) first comment. Just be sure that you are linking to a correct directory since the directory name may change from lib to lib64